# How to troubleshoot a failing Django LDAP connection

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ldap, python-ldap

I am using Django Rest with active directory authentication.
I have built a simple app with the following settings:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType


# Baseline configuration.
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://ad_server.com'

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=binduser,OU=Users,OU=ad_server,DC=ad_server,DC=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "somepassword"


# Set up the basic group parameters.
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    "OU=Groups,OU=ad_server,DC=ad_server,DC=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    "(objectClass=groupOfNames)",
)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="cn")

# Simple group restrictions
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "CN=prod,OU=Groups,OU=ad_server,DC=ad_server,DC=com"
AUTH_LDAP_DENY_GROUP = "cn=disabled,ou=django,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"

# Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory.
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    'username': 'cn',
    "email": "mail",
}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "CN=prod,OU=Groups,OU=ad_server,DC=ad_server,DC=com",
    "is_staff": "CN=prod,OU=Groups,OU=ad_server,DC=ad_server,DC=com",
    "is_superuser": "CN=prod,OU=Groups,OU=ad_server,DC=ad_server,DC=com",
}

# This is the default, but I like to be explicit.
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True

# Use LDAP group membership to calculate group permissions.
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True

# Cache distinguished names and group memberships for an hour to minimize
# LDAP traffic.
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600

# Keep ModelBackend around for per-user permissions and maybe a local
# superuser.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
)
```

Running an LDAP search from the cli works just fine
However when I try to authenticate with the http://localhost:8000/admin/  I get the following error.
[image]

The terminal on the other hand doesn't show anything:
[image]

There must be a better way to troubleshoot this, I have been at it all day and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

add this in settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
"version": 1,
"disable_existing_loggers": False,
"handlers": {"console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler"}},
"loggers": {"django_auth_ldap": {"level": "DEBUG", "handlers": ["console"]}},
```

}

[logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxVj0.png)